# using array_unshift on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use `array_unshift` on a multidimensional array and can not get it to do what I want. Here is the code:

```
$dataSet = array();
$dataSet['assoc_list'] = getAssocList(); 
array_unshift($dataSet['assoc_list'], 'all');
```

The `getAssocList` function simply returns value A1,A2,A3.  I am trtying to get "all" at the top of that list to run a report later on.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/suB44F1n

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAssocList () {
    return array('A1', 'A2', 'A3');
};

$dataSet = array();
$dataSet['assoc_list'] = getAssocList(); 
array_unshift($dataSet['assoc_list'], 'all');

print_r($dataSet);
```

Your code works fine, can you show us your getAssocList() method? This is the only hidden item at the moment which could be causing you an issue.

Comment: Here it is function getAssocList(){
 global $dbObject;
 
 $sql ="SELECT assoc from association";
 $queryVals = $dbObject->selectsearch($sql);
 $returnVal=$queryVals[0]['assoc'];
 return $queryVals; 
}